# Python variable prints an extra empty line

Tags: python

A blank line in variable `currentuser`. I am getting a blank line after skull and variable is not equal to `skull`  while loop continues.

```
currentuser = subprocess.check_output('stat -f%Su /dev/console 2>&1', shell=True)
print currentuser

while not currentuser == "skull":
    time.sleep(1)
    print"waiting for user to login"

print"Script Continue"
```

Blank line after skull

python ./logedin.py

```
skull

waiting for user to login
waiting for user to login
```

Comment: You can strip the output of your `subprocess.check_output`, just add `.strip()` to the end of the line. It removes any trailing or leading whitespaces from a string (including newlines).

Comment: If you are only just learning the basics, you should probably ignore Python 2, and spend your time on the currently recommended and supported version of the language, which is Python 3.

Comment: `currentuser == 'skull\n'`.

Comment: Command-line utilities almost always output a trailing newline.  If they didn't, the next prompt would appear on the same line as the output, making it hard to tell which was which.